# how to order a result that I have got using select statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my controller to get a bunch of data to show in the view

```
    @orders = Order.select{|order| order.email==@user.email}.select{|order| order.clip_status==true}.select{|order| order.dc>0}.select{|order| ((Time.now.to_date..(CustomVideo.find_by_order_id(order.id).created_at.to_date+30.days)).count-1)<0}
```

Now I need to order it according to the created date.

I tried the following and got errors:

```
@orders = Order.select{|order| order.email==@user.email}.select{|order| order.clip_status==true}.select{|order| order.dc>0}.select{|order| ((Time.now.to_date..(CustomVideo.find_by_order_id(order.id).created_at.to_date+30.days)).count-1)<0}.order('created_at DESC')
```

And I am getting an error. How do I solve this?

```
 undefined method `order' for []:Array
```

Comment: Why all the `select` blocks and no `where` clauses?

Comment: I tried that but I want not able to do this part with where `select{|order| order.dc>0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from misuse of `select` - you use select as if `ActiveRecord::Relation` was usual array - and select used that way indeed returns `Array` instance, which doesn't respond to `ActiveRecord` scopes. I suggest you to use `where` when it's possible and to use `select` with block (which returns `Array`) after all AR scopes are applied, like this:

```
@orders = Order.where('your conditions').order('created_at DESC').select { |order| order.dc > 0 }
```

BTW, actually it's possible to replace last `select` also with `where` (which is much more efficient), like this:

```
Order.where('dc > ?', 0)
```

Comment: I left out the '' by mistake while typing the question and testing before asking the question. Will update the question.

Comment: @Aravind your problem now is probably `undefined method 'order' for Array`. If it is, it's because misuse of `select`.

Comment: I may be able to solve this using `where` statement. But I am not sure how to use the `select{|order| order.dc>0}` using `where` statement. I tried `where(:order>0)`, which is obviously wrong. What should I do?